# Swap area verification table

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, swap

I have only one OS in my PC -- UBUNTU.  I wish to double the RAM.  So, if I got a table to verify the size of the swap area space, it would be very useful (without going deep into the details); especially for installation.  I mean, the range for 1GB, 2GB, 4GB etc.  If possible please tell me a preferable swap area for each.

I wish to know the minimum & preferable PERCENTAGE of space for Root "/" when the Hard Disk is considered.

Comment: Are you asking how much space to allocate fro swap and how much to allocate for /? Have you tried searching for this information on your own? It's a very common question.

Comment: My PC has 991.5 MiB RAM and 640 GB Hard Disk. Swap area is 1.1 GB. When I change the RAM size to 2 GB, need I change the swap area? or Is it possible to alter the Swap area without affecting Ubuntu. I wish to get a table so that this thread will be useful to others also. ..... I searched for this information before posting this question. .... The link you gave was useful; but I wish to get a good answer to my question itself.

Comment: @Madhusoodanan that's a very opinion-based question, and those are off-topic on Ubuntu (as can be seen from the linked question). Try asking on [Discourse](http://discourse.ubuntu.com) or on the Ubuntu Forums.